# How do you display data points in percentage format using mschart in c#

Tags: c#, mschart

I have been trying to display percentage for my data points in ms chart in this format 00.00%. I can not figure out how.

I used this for my series label

```
chart1.Series[1].Label = "#PERCENT";
```

and it turns out like this on the chart, the values are not displaying correctly.

[image]

The data is coming from a data table and this is how I am populating the chart

```
 //Chart data points
                foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows)
                {
                    object wk = (r["week_num"]).ToString();
                    object fpy = (r["fpy"]); // First pass yield percentage
                    object thrput = (r["throughput"]).ToString();

                    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(wk, thrput);
                    chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(wk, fpy);
                }
```

I am not sure how to correct format the data points in the line graph to display the correct value and in the percentage format.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

if I remove this line

```
chart1.Series[1].Label = "#PERCENT";
```

The values are correct but not in percentage format

[image]

Comment: So you want a leading `0`? For example `04.21%`. Please clarify "not correctly"

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 2):

You will have to format the Label style

Try `chart.ChartAreas.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "{00:00}"`

actually you may have to customise the [percent specifer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierPct)

i think its' set to just show one number (before the point) by default

e.g.

```
double value = .086;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("#0.##%", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                "{0:#0.##%}", value));
// Displays 8.6%
```

you will have to override it and put in an extra zero

Answer (score 1):

I decided to convert the fpy to a decimal and remove the all decimal points. I now have the correct value displayed on my line graph data points. Thank your all for you help! :)

```
decimal fpy = Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0:F0}", ((r["fpy"])))); // First pass yield percentage
```